# Link rows by date

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to link some rows by a certain date.

Example:
I have a table A:

```
ID   Date1       Date2
11   2019-03-01  NULL
23   2019-03-01  NULL
11   2019-05-01  2019-03-01
44   2019-04-01  NULL
11   2019-06-01  2019-03-01
44   2019-06-01  2019-04-01
11   2019-07-01  NULL
```

I want my table to end up something like this:
[image]

Rows with Date2 linked to Date1 should always be nested under the primary row

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Left hand side is sample data and right hand side is Grouped with ID

[image]

How do you achieve it?

Click on Row then at bottom you will find Row Group

[image]

Inside Parent Group, Group it by ID

[image]

Note: In your question you mentioned Linked Data, I did not got what you mean by that.
Let me know above solution helps you?